# Save data between different package/apps

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have both a free and a paid app. If the user first tries `free version` and acquire for example `10 gold` and then upgrade to paid version I want him to keep those `10 gold` and not do a fresh start.

So is there way to share and access data between apps? And I don't want to save it to root of `SD card` because user can easily modify it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some developers circumvent this by using their paid app just to check the payment (if it's installed, you've paid for it) and keep everything (code wise) in the free version. You could as well just encrypt/decrypt the data written to the SD card. This would as well make it easier for the user to backup/restore those saves (and nothing would be lost in case the app is reinstalled or something like that).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! But how do I make free version check if there are a paid version?

Comment: First hit on google: http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/detect-if-an-app-is-installed But overall, think about how you'd like your users to manage their savegames (or whatever we're talking about). Do you want them to lose/being unable to transfer their saves? Guess simply having encrypted data files on your sd card is still your best available approach.

Comment: Ok that sounds plausible i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file in application data folder. And save it there.

```
 /data/data/your_complete_package/your_data_filename
```

And of course you need to encrypt it with something unique to this phone.

So they wont be able to move this file to another phone to use.

Note that file under app data folder will uninstall together with your App.

Answer (score 0):

I think Android Content providers may solve this problem:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They encapsulate the data,              >and provide mechanisms for defining data security. Content providers are the standard >interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

Your app can implement ContentProvider and export data uri you need to share, than your free & paid version can share data through ContentProvider , just like how you access Google Contracts.

BTW,ContentProvider support SQLite & XML , which means you can store it in memory or sd card as you want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would be to maintain some kind of a remote server that holds all the data for users. Users login when entering the app, authenticate themselves with the server, and have all their data available.

Any local solution isn't persistent. What if a user gets his/hers app deleted? if the phone is damaged and the app is unrecoverable?

As a paying user of any app i would like to have my paid data portable through different devices.

Just my 2 cents on the matter...